# How to quickly find $\sqrt{x^4+4x^3+2x^2-4x+1}$ or anything similar

Tags: polynomials

How to quickly find the result of $\sqrt{x^4+4x^3+2x^2-4x+1}$ or anything similar of the form  √(Q(x)) where $Q(x)=(P(x))^2$. I'm stuck

Comment: Write ${\rm P}\left(x\right)$ as a second degree polynomial. Equates coefficients in both sides.

Comment: How to find that P(x)? That's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this isn't possible. If it is possible (as here), you solve it by assuming that $\sqrt{x^4+4x^3+2x^2-4x+1}$ is of the form $ax^2+bx+c$, and solving

$$x^4+4x^3+2x^2-4x+1 = (ax^2+bx+c)^2 = a^2x^4 + 2abx^3 + (b^2+2ac)x^2 + 2bcx + c^2$$

Equating coefficients of $x^n$, we get:

$a^2=1$, so $a=\pm 1$ (and we can choose the sign of the square root so that $a = +1$)
$2ab = 4$, so $b=2$
$b^2+2ac=2$, so $c=-1$

We can always get this far. Now, to check whether the problem has a solution, find out whether the remaining terms agree:

$2bc=-4$
$c^2=1$

so these coefficients are equal too. Hence finally

$$x^4+4x^3+2x^2-4x+1 = (x^2+2x-1)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'easy' way of doing these things. Given the question, we should suspect that the polynomial under the square root, call it $P(x)$, should be of the form $x+a$ or $x^2+ax+b$ so that we can take the square root 'nicely' (meaning that we will have $\sqrt{P(x)^4}$ or $\sqrt{P(x)^2}$ depending on if $P(x)$ is of the form $x+a$ or $x^2+ax+b$).

Try $P(x)=x^2+ax+b$ and see what $a,b$ make $P(x)^2=x^4+4x^3+2x^2-4x+1$.

> This would give $P(x)^2=x^4+2ax^3+2bx^2+a^2x^2+2abx+b^2$. The last term makes it clear that $b=\pm 1$ and the second term makes it clear $2a=4$ so that $a$ is 'probably' $2$. Indeed, relating all the corresponding terms one finds $a=2$ and $b=-1$. Then we have $P(x)=x^2+2x-1$. So that $$Q(x)=\sqrt{x^4+4x^3+2x^2-4x+1}=\sqrt{P(x)^2}=P(x)$$

Comment: "There is no 'easy' way of doing these things": on the contrary, there is a perfectly simple method to find such a square root. See my answer.

Comment: @TonyK You misinterpreted my statement. Indeed, I mean the same thing you stated: that in general it's not possible to simplify expressions such as these. We simply try and hope (rightfully so as it is the case) that $P(x)$ is of the form that we can take the square root of it. Moreover, I do not need to see your answer, as I gave the same answer here which makes me think you commented before even looking at the solution.

Comment: But it's easy, right?

Comment: @TonyK Only because this is a special case. I ask you to create a general method of simplifying $\sqrt(P(x)$ for any polynomial and the question could very well be generally intractable. However, in the special case where $P(x)$ is a perfect square, then it is generally not that bad. Again, I simply outline the thought process. That one should look at things as these and go, 'Probably not possible....unless, $P(x)$ is a perfect square!, but that would mean...' and continue with the problem in such a manner.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$Q'(x)=(P^2(x))'=2P(x)P'(x)$$
and so 
$$\gcd(Q(x),Q'(x))=\gcd(P^2(x),2P(x)P'(x))=P(x)\gcd \left(P(x),2P'(x)\right)$$
$\gcd(Q(x),Q'(x))$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ so this is the root.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Write ${\rm P}\pars{x} = x^{2} + bx \pm 1$. If ${\rm Q}\pars{x}$ is a 'perfect square', you'll find a 'consistent' value of $b$:

> \begin{align}
> &x^{4} + 4x^{3} + 2x^{2} - 4x + 1 = \pars{x^{2} + bx \pm 1}^{2} = 
> x^{4} + b^{2}x^{2} + 1 + 2bx^{3} \pm 2x^{2} \pm 2bx
> \\[3mm]&=x^{4} + 2bx^{3} + \pars{b^{2} \pm 2}x^{2} \pm 2bx + 1
> \quad\imp\quad 2b = 4\,,\quad b^{2} \pm 2 = 2\,,\quad \pm 2b = - 4 
> \end{align}

Now, with the lower sign the three equations at the right are satisfied:
$$
\color{#00f}{\large{\rm P}\pars{x} = x^{2} + 2x - 1}
$$